# Zebra Datawedge Stops receiving scans

Tags: android, kotlin, datawedge, zebra-scanners

Using a Zebra MC3300 Device with Datawedge 8.0 +

I've been working on a scanning app that requires me to scan an RFID in step one and immediately scan a barcode in step two. The process is repeated to link the RFID and barcode in the DB. I've developed the app using the data wedge API but the scan is failed after a couple of scans the RFID scan doesn't scan anymore even though it is enabled and whether enable/disable the profile, restarting the app doesn't help either. When this happens I have to restart the device completely to get it to work again.

From the logs, I observed some sort of crashes and messages that I think might be helpful in understanding the issue. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
    02-07 19:19:06.021   724   724 I ScannerFramework: [Scanner::ScannerOpen] 'ScannerOpen' called, Calling process pid '1551', package name 'com.symbol.datawedge'
02-07 19:19:06.021   724   724 E ScannerFramework: [StackAdapter::ScannerOpen] User exists but Scanner not initialized
02-07 19:19:06.023   724   724 I ScannerFramework: [Scanner::ScannerOpen] - '0'
02-07 19:19:06.028   528   528 E HWComposer: getLayerReleaseFence: Invalid display
02-07 19:19:06.252   528   528 I chatty  : uid=1000(system) /system/bin/surfaceflinger identical 87 lines
02-07 19:19:06.252   528   528 E HWComposer: getLayerReleaseFence: Invalid display
02-07 19:19:06.262  1168  1183 D ActivityTrigger: ActivityTrigger activityStopTrigger 
02-07 19:19:06.266   724  1016 I ScannerFramework: [Scanner::IsScannerConnected] 'IsScannerConnected' called, Calling process pid '1551'
02-07 19:19:06.266   724  1016 I ScannerFramework: [Scanner::IsScannerConnected] - '1'
02-07 19:19:06.266   724  1169 I ScannerFramework: [564:280][Scanner::ScannerEnable] 'ScannerEnable' called, Calling process pid '1551'
02-07 19:19:06.275   528   528 E HWComposer: getLayerReleaseFence: Invalid display
02-07 19:19:06.415   528   528 I chatty  : uid=1000(system) /system/bin/surfaceflinger identical 23 lines
02-07 19:19:06.415   528   528 E HWComposer: getLayerReleaseFence: Invalid display
02-07 19:19:06.478   724  1169 I imgdec  : OCRVersionString 1.6.5.11
02-07 19:19:06.478   724  1169 I imgdec  : DecOpen ImgKit IMGKIT_8.03T01.26
02-07 19:19:06.490   724  1169 I ScannerFramework: [StateMachine::MoveState] Transition from 1 to 0 for pid -1
02-07 19:19:06.490   724  1169 I ScannerFramework: [StateMachine::MoveState] Transition from 1 to 0 for pid 1551
02-07 19:19:06.490   724  1169 I ScannerFramework: [Scanner::ScannerEnable] - '0'
02-07 19:19:06.493  1551  1551 D ImagingProxy: Inside ImagingProxy(mServiceName)com.symbol.imagingcapture
02-07 19:19:06.502   724  1169 I ScannerFramework: [StateMachine::MoveState] Transition from 0 to 5 for pid -1
02-07 19:19:06.502   724  1169 I ScannerFramework: [StateMachine::MoveState] Transition from 0 to 5 for pid 1551
02-07 19:19:06.502   724  1169 I ScannerFramework: [DigimarkCWrapper::Decinit] g_mScannerEngine : se4750_cam_builtin g_bInitDone = 1
02-07 19:19:06.513  1168  2203 E ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast com.symbol.datawedge.api.RESULT_ACTION from system 1551:com.symbol.datawedge/u0a10 pkg com.symbol.datawedge
02-07 19:19:06.513  1168  2203 E ActivityManager: java.lang.Throwable
02-07 19:19:06.513  1168  2203 E ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.checkBroadcastFromSystem(ActivityManagerService.java:19400)
02-07 19:19:06.513  1168  2203 E ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:19916)
02-07 19:19:06.513  1168  2203 E ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:20151)
02-07 19:19:06.513  1168  2203 E ActivityManager:   at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:240)
02-07 19:19:06.513  1168  2203 E ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3045)
02-07 19:19:06.513  1168  2203 E ActivityManager:   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:697)
02-07 19:19:06.522  1168  2203 E ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast com.symbol.datawedge.api.RESULT_ACTION from system 1551:com.symbol.datawedge/u0a10 pkg com.symbol.datawedge
02-07 19:19:06.522  1168  2203 E ActivityManager: java.lang.Throwable
02-07 19:19:06.522  1168  2203 E ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.checkBroadcastFromSystem(ActivityManagerService.java:19400)
02-07 19:19:06.522  1168  2203 E ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:20009)
02-07 19:19:06.522  1168  2203 E ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:20151)
02-07 19:19:06.522  1168  2203 E ActivityManager:   at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:240)
02-07 19:19:06.522  1168  2203 E ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3045)
02-07 19:19:06.522  1168  2203 E ActivityManager:   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:697)
02-07 19:19:06.526  1551  1551 D com.symbol.datawedge.api.IntentAPIManager: onReceive(..):com.symbol.datawedge.ScanningService@18323e5,Intent { act=com.symbol.datawedge.api.ACTION flg=0x10 (has extras) }
02-07 19:19:06.541  1168  1543 D CompatibilityInfo: mCompatibilityFlags - 4
02-07 19:19:06.542  1168  1543 D CompatibilityInfo: applicationDensity - 240
02-07 19:19:06.542  1168  1543 D CompatibilityInfo: applicationScale - 1.0
02-07 19:19:06.700  1168  1543 E ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast com.symbol.datawedge.api.RESULT_ACTION from system 1551:com.symbol.datawedge/u0a10 pkg com.symbol.datawedge
02-07 19:19:06.700  1168  1543 E ActivityManager: java.lang.Throwable
02-07 19:19:06.700  1168  1543 E ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.checkBroadcastFromSystem(ActivityManagerService.java:19400)
02-07 19:19:06.700  1168  1543 E ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:19916)
02-07 19:19:06.700  1168  1543 E ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:20151)
02-07 19:19:06.700  1168  1543 E ActivityManager:   at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:240)
02-07 19:19:06.700  1168  1543 E ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3045)
02-07 19:19:06.700  1168  1543 E ActivityManager:   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:697)
02-07 19:19:06.703  1168  1543 E ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast com.symbol.datawedge.api.RESULT_ACTION from system 1551:com.symbol.datawedge/u0a10 pkg com.symbol.datawedge
02-07 19:19:06.703  1168  1543 E ActivityManager: java.lang.Throwable
02-07 19:19:06.703  1168  1543 E ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.checkBroadcastFromSystem(ActivityManagerService.java:19400)
02-07 19:19:06.703  1168  1543 E ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:20009)
02-07 19:19:06.703  1168  1543 E ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:20151)
02-07 19:19:06.703  1168  1543 E ActivityManager:   at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:240)
02-07 19:19:06.703  1168  1543 E ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3045)
02-07 19:19:06.703  1168  1543 E ActivityManager:   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:697)
02-07 19:19:06.706  1551  1551 D com.symbol.datawedge.api.IntentAPIManager: onReceive(..):com.symbol.datawedge.ScanningService@18323e5,Intent { act=com.symbol.datawedge.api.ACTION flg=0x10 (has extras) }
02-07 19:19:06.943  1425  1425 D KeyguardUpdateMonitor: received broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
02-07 19:19:06.947  1425  1425 D KeyguardUpdateMonitor: handleBatteryUpdate
02-07 19:19:06.947  1397  1785 D HeadsetStateMachine: Disconnected process message: 10, size: 0
02-07 19:19:06.947  1397  1785 D HeadsetStateMachine: Enter processIntentBatteryChanged()
02-07 19:19:06.947  1397  1785 D HeadsetStateMachine: Exit processIntentBatteryChanged()
02-07 19:19:06.948  1397  1785 D HeadsetStateMachine: Exit Disconnected processMessage() 
02-07 19:19:06.948  5492  5492 D com.symbol.dataanalytics.a.a.d.b: Received battery event
02-07 19:19:06.948  5492  5492 D com.symbol.dataanalytics.a.a.d.b: BatteryFactory event action = android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
02-07 19:19:06.972   528   528 E HWComposer: getLayerReleaseFence: Invalid display
02-07 19:19:06.989   528   528 I chatty  : uid=1000(system) /system/bin/surfaceflinger identical 8 lines
02-07 19:19:06.989   528   528 E HWComposer: getLayerReleaseFence: Invalid display
02-07 19:19:07.040   724  1017 I ScannerFramework: [Scanner::ClearReadSubmit] 'ClearReadSubmit' called, Calling process pid '1551'
02-07 19:19:07.040   724  1017 I ScannerFramework: [StateMachine::MoveState] Transition from 5 to 0 for pid -1
02-07 19:19:07.041   724  1017 I ScannerFramework: [StateMachine::MoveState] Transition from 5 to 0 for pid 1551
02-07 19:19:07.041   724  1017 I ScannerFramework: [Scanner::ClearReadSubmit] - '0'
02-07 19:19:07.041   724  1016 I ScannerFramework: [Scanner::ScannerDisable] 'ScannerDisable' called, Calling process pid '1551'
02-07 19:19:07.079   528   528 E HWComposer: getLayerReleaseFence: Invalid display
02-07 19:19:07.079   528   528 I chatty  : uid=1000(system) /system/bin/surfaceflinger identical 3 lines
02-07 19:19:07.079   528   528 E HWComposer: getLayerReleaseFence: Invalid display
02-07 19:19:07.111   724  1016 I ScannerFramework: [StateMachine::MoveState] Transition from 0 to 1 for pid -1
02-07 19:19:07.111   724  1016 I ScannerFramework: [StateMachine::MoveState] Transition from 0 to 1 for pid 1551
02-07 19:19:07.111   724  1016 W ScannerFramework: [StateMachine::MoveState] Transition from 1 to 1 is invalid
02-07 19:19:07.111   724  1016 I ScannerFramework: [Scanner::ScannerDisable] - '0'
02-07 19:19:07.111  1551  1551 D ScanningProxy: Inside ScannerRelease(). ReferenceCounter value=1
02-07 19:19:07.112   724  1169 I ScannerFramework: [Scanner::ScannerRelease] 'ScannerRelease' called, Calling process pid '1551'
02-07 19:19:07.112   724  1169 I ScannerFramework: [Scanner::ScannerRelease] - '0'
02-07 19:19:07.167  1551  1551 D ScanningProxy: Inside ScannerOpen().... mReferenceCounter=0
02-07 19:19:07.167   724   724 I ScannerFramework: [Scanner::ScannerOpen] 'ScannerOpen' called, Calling process pid '1551', package name 'com.symbol.datawedge'
02-07 19:19:07.167   724   724 E ScannerFramework: [StackAdapter::ScannerOpen] User exists but Scanner not initialized
02-07 19:19:07.168   724   724 I ScannerFramework: [Scanner::ScannerOpen] - '0'
02-07 19:19:07.472   724  1016 I ScannerFramework: [Scanner::IsScannerConnected] 'IsScannerConnected' called, Calling process pid '1551'
02-07 19:19:07.472   724  1016 I ScannerFramework: [Scanner::IsScannerConnected] - '1'
02-07 19:19:07.473   724  1169 I ScannerFramework: [565:487][Scanner::ScannerEnable] 'ScannerEnable' called, Calling process pid '1551'
02-07 19:19:07.676   724  1169 I imgdec  : OCRVersionString 1.6.5.11

02-07 19:19:08.042  1551  1551 I RfidServiceManager: Constructor of RfidServiceManager
02-07 19:19:08.048  1551  1551 D RFIDAPI3: bindtoService
02-07 19:19:08.050  1551  1551 D RFIDAPI3: bindtoService registerReceiver
02-07 19:19:08.050  1168  1569 I rfid_service: GetAvailableReader
02-07 19:19:08.050  1168  1569 I RFIDSERVICE-RFIDService: GetAvailableReaders: [1551] <MC3300R20161523020090>
02-07 19:19:08.066  1551  1551 D RFIDAPI3: Connect
02-07 19:19:08.066  1551  1551 D RFIDAPI3: bindtoService
02-07 19:19:08.066  1551  1551 D RFIDAPI3: bindtoService registerReceiver
02-07 19:19:08.067  1168  1595 I rfid_service: Connect
02-07 19:19:08.067  1168  1595 I RFIDSERVICE-RFIDService: Connect: Attempting to connect, Client Name: MC3300R20161523020090, Client PID: 1551
02-07 19:19:08.109  1168  1387 W Binder  : Outgoing transactions from this process must be FLAG_ONEWAY
02-07 19:19:08.109  1168  1387 W Binder  : java.lang.Throwable
02-07 19:19:08.109  1168  1387 W Binder  :  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:754)
02-07 19:19:08.109  1168  1387 W Binder  :  at com.zebra.rfid.api3.IRFIDDeviceDataCallBack$Stub$Proxy.onData(IRFIDDeviceDataCallBack.java:95)
02-07 19:19:08.109  1168  1387 W Binder  :  at com.zebra.rfid.RFIDClientConnection.sendData(RFIDClientConnection.java:205)
02-07 19:19:08.109  1168  1387 W Binder  :  at com.zebra.rfid.RFIDCommMgr$DataWriteThread.run(RFIDCommMgr.java:393)
02-07 19:19:08.136  1551  1551 D API3Android: API3Android Connect status = 0
02-07 19:19:08.231   502   502 D WifiHAL : In DebugCommand::handleResponse
02-07 19:19:08.231   502   502 D WifiHAL : len = 4, expected len = 4
02-07 19:19:08.233   502   502 D WifiHAL : In DebugCommand::handleResponse
02-07 19:19:08.233   502   502 D WifiHAL : len = 4, expected len = 4
02-07 19:19:08.262  1168  1255 D WifiStateMachine: fetchRssiLinkSpeedAndFrequencyNative rssi=-61 linkspeed=144 freq=2462
02-07 19:19:08.422  1168  2170 E ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast com.symbol.datawedge.api.RESULT_ACTION from system 1551:com.symbol.datawedge/u0a10 pkg com.symbol.datawedge
02-07 19:19:08.422  1168  2170 E ActivityManager: java.lang.Throwable
02-07 19:19:08.422  1168  2170 E ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.checkBroadcastFromSystem(ActivityManagerService.java:19400)
02-07 19:19:08.422  1168  2170 E ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:19916)
02-07 19:19:08.422  1168  2170 E ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:20151)
02-07 19:19:08.422  1168  2170 E ActivityManager:   at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:240)
02-07 19:19:08.422  1168  2170 E ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3045)
02-07 19:19:08.422  1168  2170 E ActivityManager:   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:697)
02-07 19:19:08.423  1168  2170 E ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast com.symbol.datawedge.api.RESULT_ACTION from system 1551:com.symbol.datawedge/u0a10 pkg com.symbol.datawedge
02-07 19:19:08.423  1168  2170 E ActivityManager: java.lang.Throwable
02-07 19:19:08.423  1168  2170 E ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.checkBroadcastFromSystem(ActivityManagerService.java:19400)
02-07 19:19:08.423  1168  2170 E ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:20009)
02-07 19:19:08.423  1168  2170 E ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:20151)
02-07 19:19:08.423  1168  2170 E ActivityManager:   at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:240)
02-07 19:19:08.423  1168  2170 E ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3045)
02-07 19:19:08.423  1168  2170 E ActivityManager:   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:697)
02-07 19:19:08.425  1551  1551 D com.symbol.datawedge.api.IntentAPIManager: onReceive(..):com.symbol.datawedge.ScanningService@18323e5,Intent { act=com.symbol.datawedge.api.ACTION flg=0x10 (has extras) }
02-07 19:19:08.459  1551  1551 D ScanningProxy: Inside ScannerOpen().... mReferenceCounter=0
02-07 19:19:08.460   724  1169 I ScannerFramework: [Scanner::ScannerOpen] 'ScannerOpen' called, Calling process pid '1551', package name 'com.symbol.datawedge'
02-07 19:19:08.460   724  1169 E ScannerFramework: [StackAdapter::ScannerOpen] User exists but Scanner not initialized
02-07 19:19:08.461   724  1169 I ScannerFramework: [Scanner::ScannerOpen] - '0'
```

Comment: I'm having similar problem with EMDK 9.1.1 for Zebra device TC53 (also older devices).  I get intermittent failures where the device stops scanning.  Press "scan" button, red laser does not come on.  These types of errors come out in `logcat`.  Re-booting the android device does seem to clear the error.  Sometimes even just re-booting our custom scanning android App will also fix the problem.  But we have no idea what is causing the problem or how to avoid it.

Comment: Any one got any solution why its happening ..